# Masonry places blocks with huge spaces between them

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is a huge problem with masonry: it makes some useless spaces between blocks. I already tried everything, but nothing helps it.I would really apreciate if someone could tell me how to resolve this problem. Check screenshot.[Result](http://cs625717.vk.me/v625717845/48a93/CtdEFWzGjlw.jpg)
UPDATE: I figured out, that the problem starts with first figure "T-Shirts". Somehow, when I delete class width-1 from there everything fits as it's meant to be. 
Why is it happening and how can I solve this problem? Any suggestions? I really can't delete that figure, there must be some way to fit it with other blocks. Please help.

```js
var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
  // options
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 230
});

// element argument can be a selector string
//   for an individual element
var msnry = new Masonry( '.grid', {
  // options
});
```

```css
main 
{
 height: 630px;
 margin-top: 40px;
 margin-left: 18%;
 width: 1500px;
}

figcaption
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
    height: 41px;
 bottom: 0px;
 padding-top: 13px;
 padding-left: 20px;
    font-size: 21.333px;
    font-family: "SegoeUIBold";
    opacity: 0.8; 
    background-color: #FFF;
}

.grid-item
{
 width: 230px;
 height: 180px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 float: left;
}
.height-1
{
 height: 370px;
}

.width-1
{
 width: 360px;
}

.width-2
{
 width: 470px;
}

.height-2
{
 width: 360px;
 height: 370px;
}

.width-2 img 
{
 width: 470px;
 height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">
      <figure class="grid-item height-1 width-1">
        <img src="img/greenTshirt.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>T-Shirts</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/cards.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Cards</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/pens.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Pens &amp; Pencils</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item width-2">
        <img src="img/notebooks.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Notebooks</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/toys.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Toys</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item height-1">
        <img src="img/bags.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Bags</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/scrum.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Scrum cards</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/magnets.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Magnets</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item width-1">
        <img src="img/redCaps.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Caps</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/magnets.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Magnets</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/pens.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Pens &amp; Pencils</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <figure class="grid-item">
        <img src="img/toys.png" alt="">
        <figcaption>Toys</figcaption>
      </figure>
  </main>
```

Comment: It is hard to see the problem  without the images, but I think the problem is that images don't have width 100%. Try .grid-item img
{width: 100%; float:left;}

Comment: Well, I added link to pic, where it's visible what is wrong. I just couldn't add pic here, cause I don't have enough reputation points yet.

Comment: You can try with [lorempixel.com](lorempixel.com) to get a better idea

Comment: If we could see the live result it'll be great.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing imagesLoaded.

example:

```
// init Masonry
var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
  // options...
});
// layout Masonry after each image loads
$grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
  $grid.masonry('layout');
});
```